# setInterval- not rendering after condition fulfill in Vuejs Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My condition is running but I want to render after fulfilling the condition with the dynamic time you can see me code below

```
mounted() {
    this.setTimeOutClose(); 
}, 
method: {
 setTimeOutClose() {
    var now_time = moment().format('h:mm:ss A');               
    var end_time = moment(localStorage.getItem('created_at')).add(1, 'minutes').format('h:mm:ss A');
    setInterval(function() {
        if(now_time == end_time){
            alert("Did Something");
        }
    }, 1000);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get current time **inside** the setTimeout callback

```js
function setTimeOutClose() {    
    const end_time = moment().add(1, 'minutes').format('h:mm A');
    
    let operationExecuted = false
  
    setInterval(function() {
        const now_time = moment().format('h:mm A');
        if(!operationExecuted && now_time == end_time){
            console.log("Did Something");
            alert("Did Something");
            operationExecuted = true
        }
    }, 1000);
 }

setTimeOutClose()
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

### Previous answer:

Possible reasons can be:

1. **String date format ('h:mm:ss A').** You use seconds and your setInterval executed every one second. In this case, you can miss the needed time of execution. For instance, try to use **'h:mm A'**
2. **Format of 'created_at'.** It can be in a format that moment.js can't recognize (or it recognize it wrong)

Comment: Thanks, @Anatoly Zolotov for replying to me..

now_time 3:52 PM
localStorage_time 2021-06-01T10:52:30.000000Z
end_time 3:53 PM

Comment: Ok, thanx. I'll try to reproduce on my machine.
By the way, why do you use SetInterval with all this Date arithmethic? Can it be replaced with setTimeout(function, 60000)?

Comment: Dear I want to dynamic the interval part on every create time will increase then will fulfill condition according to that

Comment: @Spiral I edited the answer, check, please